# onsen ui carousel - event on show

Tags: mobile, carousel, onsen-ui

Is there any way to trigger an event when a certain Carousel item is displayed?

Below I put a code example, and want it performed a doSomething() function when the last item is shown:

```html
<ons-template id="carrossel1.html">
  <ons-page ng-controller="CarrosselController">
 <ons-carousel fullscreen swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll>
  <ons-carousel-item ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4]" id="item{{item}}">
   Carousel Item {{item}} {{html}}
  </ons-carousel-item>
  <ons-carousel-item ng-repeat="item in [1]">
   FINAL (when this is show, I need to execute doSomething() function)
  </ons-carousel-item>
 </ons-carousel>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

How to do this?

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Carousel methods here](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-carousel.html#methods-summary). You can use `on(eventName, listener)` with the event `postchange`. That will trigger every time the carousel is changed, and then in the listener just check which index is active with `getActiveCarouselItemIndex()`.

Hope it helps!